# sql query gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys getting this syntax error on my sql query:

> '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A (Status) VALUES ("NOK") INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.Typ = S.Typ WHERE A.B' at line 1

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO lm_Artikel A INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S 
ON A.Typ = S.Typ (Status) VALUES ("NOK") WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

Can you help me to find the error i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html first.

Comment: How many columns are in the **lm_Artikel** table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO lm_Artikel (Status)
SELECT 'NOK' 
FROM lm_Artikel A 
INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.Typ = S.Typ  
WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

Comment: No i want to insert "NOK" not select it

Comment: @Pgr456 - This will do exactly what you are trying to do in your query you posted. This will insert `NOK` into the status column of the table `lm_Artikel` by insuring that the `typ` value in the two tables are equal and `A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert`. Try it. If this isn't what you meant, please explain what are you trying to do. Thanks

Comment: to make it clearer this is another version i had done which also gives an syntax error: `INSERT INTO lm_Artikel A (Status) VALUES ("NOK") INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.Typ = S.Typ WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert` Tried yours and gives me syntacx error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A (Status) SELECT 'NOK' FROM lm_Artikel A INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.' at line 1`

Comment: @Pgr456 - This isn't the correct syntax to do this. You have to write it this way [**`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) without the values keyword. What is the problem in the query I posted.

Comment: The query you posted gives me an error. Its this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A (Status) SELECT 'NOK' FROM lm_Artikel A INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.' at line 1`

Comment: @Pgr456 - Sorry remove the alias `A`: `INSERT INTO lm_Artikel (Status)`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO  lm_Artikel  (status)
select "NOK" from lm_Schwellwert S INNER JOIN lm_Artikel A
WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```